# Help with regex to detect urls in a string

Tags: java, regex

Hi guys
i found this regex to detect urls in a string and wraps them inside the  tag

```
public static String detectUrls(String text) {
    String newText = text
            .replaceAll("(?<!http://)www\\.[\\w/%.\\-?&=]+", "http://$0")
            .replaceAll("(?:https?|ftps?|http?)://[\\w/%.\\-?&=]+",
                    "<a href='$0'>$0</a>");
    return newText;
}
```

but this regex doesn't work with the following pattern:

https://www.myserver.com

so please advise.

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519134/issues-with-my-regex-to-detect-urls-in-a-string/4519415#4519415

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
.replaceAll("(?<!http://)www\\.[\\w/%.\\-?&=]+", "http://$0")
```

Changes `https://www.myserver.com` to `https://http://www.myserver.com`

It does exactly has you've instructed it. You need to add `https`, and probably `ftps?` to the lookbehind as well.

You may also ignore the protocol:

```
.replaceAll("(?<!://)www\\.", "http://$0")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is maybe you want:

```
public static String detectLinks(String text) {
        String newText = text.replaceAll(
                "(?<!(http|https|ftps)://)www\\.[\\w/%.\\-?&=]+", "$0")
                .replaceAll("(?<!://)www\\.", "http://$0").replaceAll(
                        "(?:https?|ftps?|http?)://[\\w/%.\\-?&=+#]+",
                        "<a href='$0'>$0</a>")

        return newText;
    }
```